# Free screen annotation for Windows 7?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Live screen annotation?](https://superuser.com/questions/202414/live-screen-annotation)

I found [SlideMate](http://www.ypgsoft.com/?p=34) but doesn't seem to work on my Windows 7 PC using F11 or F12 hotkey.

I don't want screen capture, I want live annotation (SlideMate does this).

Comment: Could you explain a little bit what you mean by "live annotation"? What to you want to annotate, and how?

Comment: I want to draw on the screen directly not make a screenshot picture and then annotate it.

Comment: duplicate of [Live screen annotation?](http://superuser.com/questions/202414/live-screen-annotation). The same answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) by Microsoft Sysinternals?

> ZoomIt is screen zoom and annotation tool for technical presentations that include application demonstrations. ZoomIt runs unobtrusively in the tray and activates with customizable hotkeys to zoom in on an area of the screen, move around while zoomed, and draw on the zoomed image. I wrote ZoomIt to fit my specific needs and use it in all my presentations.
>
> ZoomIt works on all versions of Windows and you can use pen input for ZoomIt drawing on tablet PCs.
>
> The first time you run ZoomIt it presents a configuration dialog that describes ZoomIt's behavior, let's you specify alternate hotkeys for zooming and for entering drawing mode without zooming, and customize the drawing pen color and size. I use the draw-without-zoom option to annotate the screen at its native resolution, for example. ZoomIt also includes a break timer feature that remains active even when you tab away from the timer window and allows you to return to the timer window by clicking on the ZoomIt tray icon.

[image]

Comment: beside, note this question is very similar to http://superuser.com/questions/202414/live-screen-annotation/227245#227245

Comment: No it's not similar I'm asking for Windows 7 not Windows XP.

Comment: Had heard about zoom it for ... zooming not for annotation :) I see in description that it could also do it so I'll try thanks.